# Which is the signature of a virtual function for a tailed function which use decltype to deduce return type in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual-functions, auto, decltype

I have a class with some (not pure) virtual functions which I use as a base type for other classes:

```
struct abstract_object {
    ...
}
```

in some of my other classes I need this tailed method:

```
struct Int : public abstract_object {
 
    /*virtual*/auto sum(Int* v) -> decltype(*this + *v) { return *this + *v; }
}
```

in all honesty, I don't know if this is legal, but, can I write a virtual version for the method in the base class? Until now I failed to find the right signature. c++11 is all I can stretch to.
Thanks for your help

Comment: I see one virtual function, and decltype on another, unrelated function. What are you asking about?

Comment: I think return type is deduced at compile time. Can you point out where is runtime polymorphism in above code? As both `do_this` has diff args and return type.

Comment: Um, nowhere: `do_this` is not overriden, due to signature mismatch. It has to accept a pointer to `abstract_object`. Would it bear the `override` keyword, the compiler would point to the problem.

Comment: As numzero suggested can you try to use `override` keyword you might get compiler error

Comment: Or you can put =0 between ) and { to make it an abstract base class

Comment: I just put the other methods to give some kind of sense to the code, but I achieved the opposite. I will edit the code

Comment: For a private wrapper function, it's fine for the implementation to determine the signature.  For a public virtual function, considering the implementation is the tail wagging the dog.  **Public interface drives implementation, implementation does not drive public interface.**  Your problem is that you have completely skipped *thinking* about the public interface, with the result that you are treating the `virtual` keyword as some sort of magic that allows polymorphism, rather than as a contract between called function and its caller.

Comment: @Ben Voigt The Int class IS the public interface, I'm  only trying to find e decent way to implement it "Your problem is that you have completely skipped thinking about the public interface, with the result that you are treating the virtual keyword as some sort of magic that allows polymorphism" NO I'm not, I know how polymorphism works.

Comment: @AntonioMolinaro: You just proved my point actually.  The class declaring the virtual functions IS the public interface, not the class implementing them.  Since you're asking what the signature should be in the base class (`struct abstract_object`), then `struct abstract_object` is your public interface.  You may know how virtual dispatch *works* (v-table lookup etc) but you are neglecting what polymorphism *means* (substitutability)

Comment: When you apply the LSP here, you may either discover what the contract between a caller of `abstract_object::sum()` and an implementer such as `Int::sum()` is, or you may find that this operation doesn't work under LSP, in which case you don't put a pure virtual declaration in the base class at all (and then `struct Int` is the public interface as you said).

Comment: To facilitate thinking about the problem, if you have `vector<abstract_object> v { Int(42), Double(PI), Complex(0, 1) }; vector<abstract_object> sums; for( auto& e : v ) sums.push_back(e.sum(Int(1)));` what should be the data type of the three elements placed in `sums`?

Comment: Complex + Int would be illegal, Int + Double, Double, Int + Int, Int

Comment: @AntonioMolinaro: It's not C++ you are struggling with, it is the software design.  Are you thinking of another language in which this would work?  Does that other language perhaps pass everything by reference not by value?  You could do pass-by-reference in C++ if you choose, then your signature will be `unique_ptr<abstract_object> sum(abstract_object* other)`.  `Int::sum(Int)` will call `make_unique<Int>`, `Double::sum(Int)` will call `make_unique<Double>`, and `Complex::sum(Int)` will return nullptr.

Comment: But since you have revealed that you have in mind that calling `sum()` on a mixed collection results in a variety of different data types, you need the extra layer of indirection which a pointer or reference provides, and since C++ doesn't do garbage collection, a smart pointer makes the most sense.

Comment: abstract_object works as garbage collector, too

Comment: You might look at how standard C++ `<iostream>` does this.  An `iostream` object holds a `streambuf` pointer.  The inheritance is done on `streambuf`, `filebuf`, `stringbuf`, etc.  `iostream` itself has no virtual functions, all polymorphic behavior is done by forwarding to virtual functions on the `streambuf` instance.

Comment: this is a good hint since I'm writing a language

Comment: If you used a similar approach, then every operation would return a `generic_object` but some `generic_object` would point to a `Int` inside, some to a `Double`, some to a `Complex`, some to an `Error`.  All these other classes would derive from `abstract_contents` not from `abstract_object` (which is no longer abstract, hence renaming to `generic_object`)

Comment: I wasn't saying "you skipping thinking about LSP" in order to be insulting, I said it because looking at the contract between the interface (`abstract_object` or `generic_object`) callers and implementers is the way to an actual solution.  Note that the thought exercise above is a trick question in C++, `vector<abstract_object> v { Int(42), Double(PI), Complex(0, 1) };` causes slicing and you don't have an `Int`, `Double`, and `Complex` in the vector.  Only `abstract_object`.

Comment: So we need to start by storing pointers in our vector... making `generic_object` BE a pointer to `abstract_contents` checks that box.  Now Int-vs-Double-vs-Complex is not part of the `generic_object` type, it is part of its value, and that also makes it easy to choose the return type of `sum()` to be `generic_object` and require implementers to produce a value pointing to the right type of contents.

Comment: This make sense from a design prospective as the (language) objects I'm representing with these classes are just reference to values. Maybe adding a Value class or an abstract_content, as you proposed, should help me to write a clear implementation.